# Why (3).constructor is valid while "constructor" in (3) is not valid?

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

`(3).constructor` is Number, but `"constructor" in (3)` is TypeError, why?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you post _code_ examples?

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear.  The expression `((3).constructor)` returns the Number function, while the expression `("constructor" in (3))` throws a TypeError.  The point being that 3 acts like an object, so the fact that it doesn't work with `in` is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With using the [property accessor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1), the number `3` is turned into an object of *Number*. And an object of that type has a constructor and thus an `constructor` property.

But [as ChaosPandion already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097166/why-3-constructor-is-valid-while-constructor-in-3-is-not-valid/4097204#4097204), the [`in` operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.7) requires the right expression to yield an object but `3` is not an object but a plain number literal.

Answer (score 3):

The specification for the `in` operator explains this. Specifically, see step 5 of semantic evaluation.

**11.8.7 The in operator**

The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:

1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
5. If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
6. Return the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of rval with argument ToString(lval).

The reason `(3).constructor` works is a a bit more challenging to understand but essentially when you use the dot operator on a reference with a primitive base it gets lifted into an object.

Comment: Isn't everything eventually an object in JS?

Comment: I thought that was Java, in JS it's all just var unless specified differently.Then again I don't know anything about JS. Just know java has 100% OOP

Comment: @cHao, @Proclyon - JavaScript has the concept of a *"primitive value"* which includes the following types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, String.